# Keep named items after death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

We all have lost that enchanted armour set or a efficiency v pickaxe in lava once. It's painful to see that item that consumed so many resources to craft be destroyed by lava.

I was thinking about a set of command blocks that will retrieve any ***NAMED ITEM*** from your inventory once you die, and return it to your inventory upon respawning. Any other items will be dropped to the ground, waiting for you to pick them back or be destroyed by lava.

Is it possible to create such a mechanism?

If possible, I'd love to see that the recovered items would suffer a 20% durability loss, in order to discourage the user from not caring about death.

---

I am familiar with the `/gamerule keepInventory true` command, but I find it highly overpowered, and which makes death a mere nuisance rather than something to be feared.

***No mods... this is a vanilla server.***

Comment: I don't think there is such a systems. But NEI supports such item favorite systems.

Comment: the problem with NEI is that it is one step close to whole scale cheating... and we want to create our stuff without cheating

Comment: There is absolutely no way to do this without to program the plugin for it yourself, which is possible to do in vanilla. Better learn programming :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can kind of do it but the name has to be that same you can't just have a random name, what you can do is a **/testfor** command and if it comes out false you give them a tool and the command you would use would be like.
**/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_pickaxe",tag:{display:{Name:"The Digger"}}}]}**
But you would replace minecraft:diamond_pickaxe with the item and The Digger with the name but like I said the name has to be pre-made but you won't be able to detect the durability of it but you could give them a half damaged tool or something instead of a full one by using if it was a diamond pickaxe
**/give [player] minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 781 {display:{Name:"The Digger"}}**
But the is no way to detect the damage previously on the tool